# while running npm run build "Creating an optimized production build... Failed to compile. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')"

Tags: reactjs, build, build-error, npm-run

After completion of project ,i run npm run build but unable to build error showing .

```
npm run build

> pcrf-portal@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
```

i tried in my all codes but in codes no error is there.with includes.
i'm expecting to build my project completely by running npm run build.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. And there is no 'includes' word in my project. I suspect about npm versions but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a pretty good chance that the `includes` method you are using on a variable/function has initially not defined or not returning any value. That's how it's throwing the `undefined`. In such cases, You can use some sort of condition like `if` before calling the `includes` or you can declare some empty values to it initially.

Comment: if (jsonvalue != undefined && jsonvalue !== "") {
                    if (value.toLowerCase().includes("date")) {
                      const currentDate =
                        jsonvalue.getFullYear().toString() +
                        "-" +
                        ("0" + (jsonvalue.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
                        "-" +
                        ("0" + jsonvalue.getDate()).slice(-2);

                      jsonvalue = currentDate;
                    }

Comment: but if i have removed all the the includes also same error is showing while build.

Comment: Please provide the error stack trace, so that we can try to figure out the actual issue or CSB if possible.

Answer (score 0):

try to find out where you have used `.includes` inside project.
and lets say you are using like this

```
variable.includes
```

instead of this, use

```
variable?.includes
```

Comment: i used includes only the above only.

Comment: if (jsonvalue != undefined && jsonvalue !== "") {if (value.toLowerCase().includes("date")) {const currentDate =jsonvalue.getFullYear().toString() +"-" +("0" + (jsonvalue.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +"-" +("0" + jsonvalue.getDate()).slice(-2);jsonvalue = currentDate;}s = s + value + "=" + jsonvalue + "&"; displaySearchText =displaySearchText + value + " = " + jsonvalue + " & ";}

Comment: `if (value?.toLowerCase().includes("date"))` try this

Comment: if (value?.toLowerCase().includes("date")) 

i changed to this but same error is showing while building application.

Comment: can you give me some context about what exactly the `value` is? I mean value variable is of which type int, string or something else?

Comment: value typeof is string.